# VBA to volour each marker in a scatter plot based on adjacent cell values

Tags: excel, vba

want to colour all the markers in a series (XY values in Columns O and P of Reviewed Data tab) based on values in Reviewed Data Tab Column W

```
Sub ColorScatterPoints()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim pt As Point
    Dim p As Long
    Dim Vals$, lTrim#, rTrim#
    Dim valRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim myColor As Long

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("EastingNorthingGraph").Chart
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection("Survey Point")

    ' Get the series Y-Values range address (columns N and O in Reviewed Data tab
    lTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",", InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",") - 1, _
                     vbBinaryCompare) + 1
    rTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",")
    Vals = Mid(srs.Formula, lTrim, rTrim - lTrim)
    Set valRange = Range(Vals)

    For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
        Set pt = srs.Points(p)
        'Colour lookup value is in Col W of Reviewed Data tab
        Set cl = valRange(p).Offset(0, 9)
        With pt.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            Select Case LCase(cl)
                Case "Crop"
                    myColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Case "Gravel"
                    myColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
                Case "Native Grass"
                    myColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End Select
            .ForeColor.RGB = myColor
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code? Can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: The code will change all the series colour to black or hang excel altogether. My data has Northing and Easting values in Columns N and O (values are like 580055.399, 5764681.03) and Column W will ha LandUse (either Crop, Gravel, Native Grass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new information given in your comment to my previous answer, your approach should be changed because your data set is so large. The limiting factor for your VBA approach is the time it takes to interact with each and every data point in the chart. You could move your data range into a memory-based array or disable screen updates, but with that size data set, you are still modifying each individual `Point` in the `Series`. Very time consuming.

This different approach presented takes your dataset in two columns, and creates three "virtual" datasets based on the land use data. Then we'll add three separate data series to the chart, each of which can be individually styled for color, size, style, etc.

The logic begins by creating three different ranges for the data:

```
Dim landUseWS As Worksheet
Set landUseWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim xValues As Range
Dim yValues As Range
Dim useValues As Range
With landUseWS
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Set xValues = .Range("N1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
    Set yValues = .Range("O1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
    Set useValues = .Range("W1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
End With
```

Next, I created a `Sub` to connect me to the land use chart itself. Since I'm repeatedly testing the code, moving this logic into a separate sub gives me a chance to appropriately set up the chart.

```
Private Function GetLandUseChart(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Chart
    Dim theChart As Chart
    On Error Resume Next
    Set theChart = ws.ChartObjects("EastingNorthingGraph").Chart
    If theChart Is Nothing Then
        '--- can't find it, so create it
        Dim newObject As ChartObject
        Set newObject = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, _
                                            Width:=600, Height:=300)
        newObject.Name = "EastingNorthingGraph"
        Set theChart = newObject.Chart
        With theChart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ws.Name
        End With
    End If

    '--- delete any existing series so we have an empty chart to work with
    Do Until theChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        theChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    Set GetLandUseChart = theChart
End Function
```

The next step is to create the virtual series (`Range`) from the existing data. Your data is basically three columns: X, Y, and LandUse. We want to create a range that pairs the X and Y values with every matching land use type. The cells in the range may NOT be contiguous, so we use the `Union` function to create a range object that will "group" many different cells into a single range. I've separated this into its own function also.

```
Private Function CreateLandUseSeries(ByVal useType As String, _
                                     ByRef xValues As Range, _
                                     ByRef yValues As Range, _
                                     ByRef useValues As Range) As Range
    Dim xData As Variant
    Dim yData As Variant
    Dim useData As Variant
    xData = xValues.Value
    yData = yValues.Value
    useData = useValues.Value

    Dim useRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(useData) To UBound(useData)
        If useData(i, 1) = useType Then
            If useRange Is Nothing Then
                Set useRange = Union(xValues(i, 1), yValues(i, 1))
            Else
                Set useRange = Union(useRange, xValues(i, 1), yValues(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set CreateLandUseSeries = useRange
End Function
```

So then you can do this in your main logic:

```
Dim cropSeries As Range
Dim gravelSeries As Range
Dim nativeGrassSeries As Range
Set cropSeries = CreateLandUseSeries("Crop", xValues, yValues, useValues)
Set gravelSeries = CreateLandUseSeries("Gravel", xValues, yValues, useValues)
Set nativeGrassSeries = CreateLandUseSeries("Native Grass", xValues, yValues, useValues)
```

Finally it's a straightforward matter to add each of these series to the chart, also in its own `Sub`.

```
Private Sub AddSeries(ByVal newName As String, _
                      ByRef newSeries As Range, _
                      ByRef theChart As Chart, _
                      ByVal theMarker As XlMarkerStyle)
    Dim theSeries As Series
    With theChart
        Set theSeries = .SeriesCollection.newSeries
        With theSeries
            .Name = newName
            .xValues = newSeries.Resize(, 1)
            .Values = newSeries.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1)
            '--- add some parameters to customize the marker style
            '    color, size, etc
            .MarkerStyle = theMarker
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice how you can add a variety of parameters so you can change the marker style, color, or any other aspect for the data series.

```
AddSeries "Crop", cropSeries, landUseChart, xlMarkerStyleCircle
AddSeries "Gravel", gravelSeries, landUseChart, xlMarkerStyleDiamond
AddSeries "Native Grass", nativeGrassSeries, landUseChart, xlMarkerStyleSquare
```

Optionally, you can add logic to set the chart Title, customize the legend, and other aspects of the chart.

Here is the whole module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildLandUseChart()
    Dim landUseWS As Worksheet
    Set landUseWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim xValues As Range
    Dim yValues As Range
    Dim useValues As Range
    With landUseWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        Set xValues = .Range("N1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
        Set yValues = .Range("O1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
        Set useValues = .Range("W1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
    End With

    Dim landUseChart As Chart
    Set landUseChart = GetLandUseChart(landUseWS)

    Dim cropSeries As Range
    Dim gravelSeries As Range
    Dim nativeGrassSeries As Range
    Set cropSeries = CreateLandUseSeries("Crop", xValues, yValues, useValues)
    Set gravelSeries = CreateLandUseSeries("Gravel", xValues, yValues, useValues)
    Set nativeGrassSeries = CreateLandUseSeries("Native Grass", xValues, yValues, useValues)

    AddSeries "Crop", cropSeries, landUseChart, xlMarkerStyleCircle
    AddSeries "Gravel", gravelSeries, landUseChart, xlMarkerStyleDiamond
    AddSeries "Native Grass", nativeGrassSeries, landUseChart, xlMarkerStyleSquare

End Sub

Private Sub AddSeries(ByVal newName As String, _
                      ByRef newSeries As Range, _
                      ByRef theChart As Chart, _
                      ByVal theMarker As XlMarkerStyle)
    Dim theSeries As Series
    With theChart
        Set theSeries = .SeriesCollection.newSeries
        With theSeries
            .Name = newName
            .xValues = newSeries.Resize(, 1)
            .Values = newSeries.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1)
            '--- add some parameters to customize the marker style
            '    color, size, etc
            .MarkerStyle = theMarker
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetLandUseChart(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Chart
    Dim theChart As Chart
    On Error Resume Next
    Set theChart = ws.ChartObjects("EastingNorthingGraph").Chart
    If theChart Is Nothing Then
        '--- can't find it, so create it
        Dim newObject As ChartObject
        Set newObject = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, _
                                            Width:=600, Height:=300)
        newObject.Name = "EastingNorthingGraph"
        Set theChart = newObject.Chart
        With theChart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ws.Name
        End With
    End If

    '--- delete any existing series so we have an empty chart to work with
    Do Until theChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        theChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    Set GetLandUseChart = theChart
End Function

Private Function CreateLandUseSeries(ByVal useType As String, _
                                     ByRef xValues As Range, _
                                     ByRef yValues As Range, _
                                     ByRef useValues As Range) As Range
    Dim xData As Variant
    Dim yData As Variant
    Dim useData As Variant
    xData = xValues.Value
    yData = yValues.Value
    useData = useValues.Value

    Dim useRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(useData) To UBound(useData)
        If useData(i, 1) = useType Then
            If useRange Is Nothing Then
                Set useRange = Union(xValues(i, 1), yValues(i, 1))
            Else
                Set useRange = Union(useRange, xValues(i, 1), yValues(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set CreateLandUseSeries = useRange
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You really only have ONE problem with your code. The `Offset` used to get the land use data is off by one. Use

```
 Set cl = valRange(p).Offset(0, 8)
```

and it should work.

Since I coded it up myself just to check, here is my (slightly different) version. Note a few things:

1. Declaring variables as close as possible to where they are first used. This makes it much easier to find (and change) later on if necessary.
2. Variable names are more descriptive and make the code "read" a bit easier. In a way, it's self-documenting.
3. Using the `Split` function to obtain a `Range` string to get the x-values range. It seemed easier to me to split the `Formula` string rather than parse it a couple times.
4. Declaring variables on their own line. I know, it seems to take up more vertical space, but it makes future changes easier (personal preference). ALSO, declaring `String` with `$` and `Long` with `#` is not exactly deprecated, but it's rarely used these days.
5. Since you normalized your land use string with `LCase`, each of your `Case` statements should also be all lower case.
6. I'm using `Offset(0, 9)` because I'm using the x-values range. You used the y-values range.

Here's my (slightly different) version:

```
Sub ColorScatterPoints2()
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Dim thisChart As Chart
    Dim thisSeries As Series
    Set thisWS = ActiveSheet
    Set thisChart = thisWS.ChartObjects("EastingNorthingGraph").Chart
    Set thisSeries = thisChart.SeriesCollection("Survey Point")

    '--- establish a Range for the "x" values of the series
    '    and use it to create a Range for the Land Use data
    Dim landUseArea As Range
    Dim xValues As Range
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(thisSeries.Formula, ",")
    Set xValues = Range(tokens(1))
    Set landUseArea = xValues.Offset(0, 9)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim thisPoint As Point
    Dim myColor As Long
    For i = 1 To thisSeries.Points.Count
        Select Case LCase(landUseArea.Cells(i, 1))
            Case "crop"
                myColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case "gravel"
                myColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            Case "native grass"
                myColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End Select
        Set thisPoint = thisSeries.Points(i)
        With thisPoint.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = myColor
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, much appreciated on the coding help. It still doesn't work, Ie tried the offset at (0,8) and (0,9) as I wasn't sure where it started the offset from.

Comment: My test data only has 100rows and it worked with the offset (0.8) but all the marker fills are set to black. Also it takes about 1.5min to run the macro for 100 rows, this seems pretty long. My real data can have up to 100,00 rows